# Find the grid number of a X,Y coordinate

Tags: coordinate-systems

Let's say we have a grid separated in chunks. Each chunk contains multiple points.

[Grid and chunks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eleZY.png)

Each chunk has a number :

[Chunks numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ch21j.png)

Let's say we have a point X,Y, how do we find its grid number based on its coordinate?

[Find the chunk number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKLsg.png)

Comment: Does the tiling follow some logic?
The sizes are
(4,3), (4,3), (5,3), (4,3), (4,5), (4, 5), (5,5), (4, 5) etc etc ... Are they drawn correctly in the image?

Comment: Sorry the image is wrong, I will fix it now, they should all be the same size

Comment: Also, are you interested in solving the case for only this particular tiling, or for a more general tiling?

Comment: Are you considering only square tiles ($n\times n$) or can the height and width be different?

Comment: I'm interested in solving this in any particular tiling, making "chunk size" and "grid size" dynamic. The height and width will be the same

Comment: And how about the arrangement of the tiles? Are they always arranged in an $m\times m$ grid? (in the example picture it's $4 \times 4$)

Comment: Yes, they will always be in a (m x m) grid, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is easily solved when you consider integer division and modulus.
The grid is covered in tiles of size $n \times n$ , and the tiles are set up so that they also form a grid of size $m \times m$. Therefore, in order to build this tiling, you only need to know the integers $n$ and $m$.

The easiest approach to figuring out the tile number is to switch from base $10$ to base $m$ (in your example, $m=4$). With this approach, the **tile number for points with $x=0$ will always have last digit $0$ in base $m$**. This is actually not only true for $x=0$ but $x=0, 1, \ldots , n-1$ (width of the tile). I recommend that you pause to think about this and consider some example points, referring to the picture.

Similarly, the tile number for points with $x=n, n+1, \ldots 2n-1$ will always have last digit $1$ in base $m$. We immediately see the following pattern: the last digit of the tile number in base $m$ can be extracted by integer dividing the $x$-coordinate  by the width of the tile; 
$$
\text{last digit in base }m = \frac{x}{n} \qquad \text{(integer division)}
$$

The remaining question is to figure out the first digit(s) of the tiling number. This, of course can be extracted from the $y$-coordinate, and we see that
$$
\text{first digit(s) in base }m = \frac{y}{n} \qquad \text{(integer division)}
$$
Let's now combine these equations to auxiliary quantities:
$$
f = \frac{y}{n} \qquad s = \frac{x}{n} \qquad \text{(integer division)}
$$
We need to convert this back to base 10, and the answer becomes

> $$
> \text{Tile number} = mf + s
> $$

Let's take a numerical example. In your picture, $n=2$ and $m=4$. Therefore
$$
(x,y) = (5,3) \Rightarrow
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
f = 3/2 = 1 \\
s = 5/2 = 2
\end{array}
\right.
\Rightarrow mf+s = 4\times 1 + 2 = 6
$$
Second example: 
$$
(x,y) = (0,7) \Rightarrow
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
f = 7/2 = 3 \\
s = 0/2 = 0
\end{array}
\right.
\Rightarrow mf+s = 4\times 3 + 0 = 12
$$
Our approach seems to work.

Comment: Wow. That is perfectly clear. I possibly couldn't have asked for a better answer, thank you!